# Testing controller with xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, asp.net-core-2.0

I have webapi where it needs to call some other endpoint and get data.

My current code as follows

//http client implementation

```
public interface IHttpClientFactory
{
    HttpClient Create();
}

public class HttpClientFactory : IHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly ApplicationSettings _applicationSettings;
    HttpClient _httpClient;

    public HttpClientFactory(IOptions<ApplicationSettings> settings)
    {
        _applicationSettings = settings.Value;
    }
    public HttpClient Create()
    {
        if (_httpClient != null)
            return _httpClient;

        var client = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri($"{_applicationSettings.BaseUrl}")
        };
        _httpClient = client;
        return _httpClient;
    }
}

 public interface IGetItemsQuery
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> Execute<T>(string url);
}

public class GetItemQuery: IGetItemsQuery
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    public GetPhotosQuery(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Execute<T>(string url)
    {
        using (var response = await _httpClientFactory.Create().GetAsync($"{url}").ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            var items = JArray.Parse(resp);
            return items.ToObject<T[]>();
        }
    }
```

In my controller part

```
   private readonly IGetItemsQuery _getItemsQuery;

       public HomeController(IGetItemsQuery getItemsQuery)
    {
        _getItemsQuery = getItemsQuery;
    }

 appsettings

     "ApplicationSettings": {
      "BaseUrl": "http://someendpoint.com/"
```

}

Startup

```
   services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
        services.AddScoped<IGetItemsQuery, GetPhotosQuery>();
        services.AddScoped<IHttpClientFactory, HttpClientFactory>();
```

I want to try something like below in my test

```
     [Fact]
    public void Test_Index()
    {
        // Arrange
        var itemsQuery = new Mock<IGetItemsQuery>();
        var controller = new HomeController(itemsQuery.Object);

        // Act
        var result = controller.Index();

        // Assert
        var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
        Assert.Null(viewResult.ViewName);
    }
```

This is creating mock IGetItemsQuery but this isn't mocking the actual IHttpClientFactory.

Is there a way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your design with the abstracted dependencies there would be no need to mock a client factory in order to unit test the controller.

As you have done in your test, you mock `IGetItemsQuery`, but you have not set it up to behave as expected when invoked in the test.

If, for example, the controller method under test look something like this

```
private readonly IGetItemsQuery getItemsQuery;

public HomeController(IGetItemsQuery getItemsQuery) {
    this.getItemsQuery = getItemsQuery;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index() {
    var url = "....";

    var items = await getItemsQuery.Execute<MyItem>(url);

    return View(items);
}
```

Then an isolated unit test for the `Index` action as the method under test could look something like

```
[Fact]
public async Task Index_Should_Return_View_With_Items() {
    // Arrange
    var itemsQuery = new Mock<IGetItemsQuery>();

    var items = new MyItem[] {
        new MyItem(),
        new MyItem()
    };

    itemsQuery.Setup(_ => _.Execute<MyItem>(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(items);

    var controller = new HomeController(itemsQuery.Object);

    // Act
    var result = await controller.Index();

    // Assert        
    var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
    Assert.Null(viewResult.ViewName);
}
```